# TYPO3 inline integration of news in my own extension

Tags: model, controller, typo3, inline, tca

I am using TYPO3 v12.
I want to implement multiple news articles in my own repository.
But somehow in the frontend I can only see the last one I created.
In Backend it looks fine.

Any Ideas?

Model/Pferd
[image: Model/Pferd]

---

TCA
[image: TCA]

---

ext_tables
[image: ext_tables]

---

The Debug Output from the Controller:
[image: The Debug Output from the Controller]

---

Backend:
[image: Backend]

---

```
$pferde = $this->pferdRepository->findeMeinePferde($activeuserid);
foreach ($pferde as $pferd) {
        $termine = $this->newsRepository->findeTermine($pferd->getUid());
        foreach ($termine as $termin) {
                \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($termin);
                $pferd->setNews($termin);
        }    
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Also, what is your question? You just dumped a bunch of hard to read code.

Comment: @JulianHofmann That is still not a question.

Answer (score 1):

In `Pferd`, you defined the property `$news` as a nullable object type 'News'.

However, what you want (and have created correctly in the TCA) is an `ObjectStorage` that can contain *several* `News`-objects.

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage;

class Pferd extends AbstractEntity {
    /**
     * @var ObjectStorage<News>
     */
    public $news;

    public function getNews(): ObjectStorage
    {
        return $this->news;
    }

}
```

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Extbase/Reference/Domain/Model.html